# Issue with bwa mem process not running on all output files from previous process

Tags: nextflow

I'm building a nextflow pipeline to map and variant call genotyping by sequencing (GBS) data (single end Illumina).  I've based much of it on the nf-core/eager pipeline as that had many of the tools I want to incorporate into my pipeline. I've tested the pipeline on sample and it works perfectly.  However, when I try running the pipeline on more samples, it pulls in the read files fine and trims them with fastp.  However, when I try to run bwa mem on the trimmed files, it'll only work on one of the trimmed fastq files which it seems to pick at random which means the downstream processes only run on one file.  I've tried a few different things, none of which seem to work. I'm guessing it may be something to do with the fasta reference/bwa index not being a value channel? Any suggestions?

```
//read reference fasta channel

Channel.fromPath("${params.fasta}")
    .ifEmpty { exit 1, "No genome specified! Please specify one with --fasta or --bwa_index"}
    .into {ch_fasta_for_bwa_indexing; ch_fasta_for_faidx_indexing; ch_fasta_for_variant_call; ch_fasta_for_bwamem_mapping; ch_fasta_for_qualimap}

///build_bwa_index

process build_bwa_index {
    tag {fasta}

    publishDir path: "${params.outdir}/bwa_index", mode: 'copy', saveAs: { filename ->
            if (params.saveReference) filename
            else if(!params.saveReference && filename == "where_are_my_files.txt") filename
            else null
    }

    when: !params.bwa_index && params.fasta

    input:

    file fasta from ch_fasta_for_bwa_indexing
    file wherearemyfiles

    output:

    file "*.{amb,ann,bwt,pac,sa,fasta,fa}" into bwa_index_bwamem
    file "where_are_my_files.txt"

    """
    bwa index $fasta
    """
}

///bwa_align process

process bwa_align {
    tag "$name"

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/mapping/bwamem", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    set val(name), file(reads) from trimmed_fastq
    file fasta from ch_fasta_for_bwamem_mapping
    file "*" from bwa_index_bwamem

    output:
    file "*_sorted.bam" into bwa_sorted_bam_idxstats, bwa_sorted_bam_filter
    file "*.bai"

    script:

    if(params.singleEnd){
    """ 
    bwa mem $fasta ${reads[0]} -t ${task.cpus} | samtools sort -@ ${task.cpus} -o ${name}_sorted.bam
    samtools index -@ ${task.cpus} ${name}_sorted.bam
    """ 
    } else {
    """ 
    bwa mem $fasta ${reads[0]} ${reads[1]} -t ${task.cpus} | samtools sort -@ ${task.cpus} -o ${name}_sorted.bam
    samtools index -@ ${task.cpus} ${name}_sorted.bam
    """ 
    }

}
```

I would it expect to the bwa_align process to run on both files produced by the fastp process in this example

```
Pipeline name  : trishulagenetics/genocan
Pipeline version: 0.1dev
Run name       : exotic_hoover
Reads          : data_2/*.R{1,2}.fastq.gz
Fasta reference: GCA_000230575.4_ASM23057v4_genomic.fna
bwa index      : false
Data type      : Single-end
Max Memory     : null
Max CPUs       : null
Max Time       : null
Output dir     : ./results
Working dir    : /home/debian/Trishula/SRR2060630_split/test/work
Container Engine: docker
Container      : trishulagenetics/genocan:latest
Current home   : /home/debian
Current user   : debian
Current path   : /home/debian/Trishula/SRR2060630_split/test
Script dir     : /home/debian/.nextflow/assets/trishulagenetics/genocan
Config Profile : docker
=========================================
executor >  local (14)
[b1/080d6a] process > get_software_versions                                      [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[4e/87b4c2] process > build_bwa_index (GCA_000230575.4_ASM23057v4_genomic.fna)   [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[27/64b776] process > build_fasta_index (GCA_000230575.4_ASM23057v4_genomic.fna) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[f6/b07508] process > fastqc (P2_E07_M_0055)                                     [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
[87/ecd07c] process > fastp (P2_E07_M_0055)                                      [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
[50/e7bf8c] process > bwa_align (P2_A01_M_0001)                                  [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[c1/3647bc] process > samtools_idxstats (P2_A01_M_0001_sorted)                   [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[0c/68b22c] process > samtools_filter (P2_A01_M_0001_sorted)                     [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[de/c26b2d] process > qualimap (P2_A01_M_0001_sorted.filtered)                   [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[bc/f7cf86] process > variant_call (P2_A01_M_0001)                               [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[6f/2a9ab8] process > multiqc                                                    [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[bb/b8b957] process > output_documentation (null)                                [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[trishulagenetics/genocan] Pipeline Complete
Completed at: 17-Aug-2019 09:51:48
Duration    : 19m 34s
CPU hours   : 0.3
Succeeded   : 14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - Basically it's better to avoid splitting your fasta file into multiple channels and just use a single value which is implicitly a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel):

```
ref_fasta = file(params.fasta)

process build_bwa_index {

    storeDir ...

    input:
    file ref_fasta

    output:
    file "*.{amb,ann,bwt,pac,sa}" into bwa_index

    """
    bwa index "${ref_fasta}"
    """
}

process bwa_mem {

    publishDir ...

    input:
    set name, file(reads) from trimmed_fastq
    file ref_fasta
    file "*" from bwa_index

    ...
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks, this fixed the problem